# RegEx for validating URLs in a rewriteMap

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm writing a tool for the office to allow people to submit mappings to be used in a `rewriteMap` in a web.config file and I'm trying to validate both paths against a set of rules using RegEx but I can't quite seem to get all the bases covered so I'm looking for some help in making the 2 expressions as "bulletproof" as possible.

### General requirements for both expressions

- Should be case sensitive as they'll be used (among other places) in an HTML `input`'s `pattern` attribute.
- Should be as basic as *possible* (keyword, there) as the people that may be editing them in the future will have varying degrees of RegEx knowledge - for example, using `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` instead of `\w`.
- Match must not include the protocol (`http` or `https`) or domain (`www.domain.tld` or `domain.tld`).<sup>*</sup>

---

### Expression for `key` (paths to be redirected *from*)

What I currently have:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_].+?[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]$
```

#### Requirements

- Cannot start or end with a `/`.
- May be a directory or a file.
- May contain spaces.
- May or may not be multiple levels deep in the directory structure.
- Cannot start with certain (internally) reserved directory names - currently that list only includes `administration` but a couple more will be added.<sup>**</sup>

The following (non-exhaustive list) provides a few examples of values I need to reject:

```
VALUE                      | SHOULD BE
---------------------------|--------------
/old                       | old
/old/dir_name/             | old/dir_name
https://www.domain.tld/old | old
domain.tld/file name.ext   | file name.ext
administration             | (reject completely)
administration/dir-name    | (reject completely)
```

### Expression for `value` (paths to be redirected *to*)

What I currently have:

```
^/(.+?/(.+?[a-zA-Z0-9])?)?$
```

- Must start with a `/`.
- May be a directory or a file (but we'll primarily be redirecting to directories).
- If a directory, must end with a `/`.
- File names will always have an extension.
- Directory names will never contain a `.`.
- May contain spaces.
- May or may not be multiple levels deep in the directory structure or may be the root directory.

The following (non-exhaustive list) provides a few examples of values I need to reject:

```
VALUE                       | SHOULD BE
----------------------------|----------------
/new                        | /new/
new/dir_name                | /new/dir_name/
https://www.domain.tld/new/ | /new/
domain.tld/file name.ext    | /file name.ext
/new/dir.name/file_name.ext | (reject completely)
```

---

The relevant `rule` from the web.config file (where `Redirects` is the `name` of the `rewriteMap`), if it's relevant, is:

```
<rule name="rewriteMap">
    <match url="^(.+?)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{Redirects:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

---

<sup>* I'm currently working on that part of the RegEx; felt it best to leave it out of my examples as it's very incomplete.
** This requirement was only added after I began writing this question, which is why it's not addressed in the example RegEx.</sup>

Comment: Well-formatted question but missing sample inputs and expected matches which play an important role when asking about Regular Expressions.

Comment: @revo, that's one of the problems. For the `key`, in particular, I have no control over the possible values (URLs on sites we did not build) so it needs to be somewhat "catch-all", which is why I included the lists rather than examples; I was trying to avoid people optimising their solutions for them. I'm just about to run out for lunch but I'll update when I get back and try to add some examples with some sort of disclaimer.

Comment: You only have to let us figure out what is allowed based on the rules and what is not. The first part is more important than the second but if it doesn't crystal clear the problem the latter helps a lot.

Comment: @revo, I've added a couple of examples now.

Comment: How should a regex find if a string is a file or a directory name? For now you are saying `dir.name` couldn't be a directory and `filename` couldn't be a filename (i.e. it doesn't have an extension)

Comment: Good point, @revo. That would only affect the second RegEx where we need to decide whether or not to require the trailing slash. Luckily, though, on our system, all file names must have an extension and directory names cannot include a `.`. I've updated the question with that information as well as a note that we'll primarily be redirecting to directories.